# How to make ModalBottomSheet's child Widget protrude at the top like this pic：

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make ModalBottomSheet's child Widget protrude at the top

like this pic：

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Stack` to make the shopping bag icon position on top of the modal. The 40 in `margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40)` that is set for the container is half the height of the shopping bag icon.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                        bottomRight: Radius.zero,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 50,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Image.network('https://assets.webiconspng.com/uploads/2017/09/Shopping-Bag-PNG-Image-40241.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
```

Result:

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to Stack

```
overflow: Overflow.visible,
```

and add negative value to Positioned Widget sample:

```
Stack(
    overflow: Overflow.visible,  // add this line
    children: [
       Positioned(
          bottom: -150, // negative value
          child: Container(
             height: 80,
             width: 100,
             child: Image.network('https://assets.webiconspng.com/uploads/2017/09/Shopping-Bag-PNG-Image-40241.png'),
             )
       )])
```